# Finding strrpos of \ in a String

Tags: php, string

Here's a puzzler. I have a variable that contains computer file paths. I need to separate the filename from the path.

Example:
 From this:

```
$filepath = C:\\User\Me\Myfiles\file.jpg
```

I need this:

```
$path = C:\\User\Me\Myfiles\
$file = file.jpg
```

I know how to get the substrings of $filepath using substr. The problem is using "\" as a "needle" to get the position of the filename.

This causes an error:

```
$pos = strrpos("\",$filepath);
```

This doesn't cause an error, but doesn't give me a value for $pos:

```
$pos = strrpos("\\",$filepath);
```

As always, any help with be rewared with my eternal gratitude.

Comment: Look at the manual again. It says [`strrpos($haystack, $needle)`](http://php.net/strrpos)

Comment: I'd much rather have the reward of an accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks all for your uber quick response. Now that I see the answer (below), I must apologize for the question. Sometimes my alter ego "Le Grande Idiot Man" takes over my brain!!! Once again, a thousand thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$pos = strrpos("\\",$filepath);
```

This is trying to find the position of `$filepath` in the string `"\\"`. Unless the `$filepath` is a single backslash, no position will be returned.

You want to swap the two arguments around.

```
$pos = strrpos($filepath, "\\");
```

---

Also, [`basename($filepath)`](http://php.net/basename) or [`pathinfo($filepath, PATHINFO_BASENAME)`](http://php.net/pathinfo) can be used to get the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output of [`pathinfo($filepath)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php), or for an oo approach, at the available methods of [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php).

Comment: Creating an `SplFileInfo` object is a little extreme just to get the file name from a path.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('#^(.+)\\\\(.+)$#', $filepath, $matches);
$path = $matches[1];
$file = $matches[2];
```

This works because the `+` regex quantifier is greedy, so it will match all the characters it can.  The `\` is double-escaped, once for the PHP string, and once for the regex.